# Get a specific part of a String in Java

Tags: java, string

I want to get specific parts of a String like:

```
@org.junit.runners.Suite$SuiteClasses(value=[class data.XTest
, class data.YTest])
```

`data.XTest` and `data.YTest` are variable.
Whats the best way to get the classes after the `class`.

Required output:

```
sTring[0] = data.XTest;
sTring[1] = data.YTest;
```

Comment: Do you *really* want them in an array?

Comment: or a List. The thing is how to best get the parts of this String so I can work with them with reflect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one-liner:

```
String[] parts = input.replaceAll(".*\\[class (.*)\\].*", "$1").split(", class ");
```

This works by first using regex to extract the substring between `"...[class "` and `"]"`, then splits on the separating chars to neatly pluck out the target strings.

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "@org.junit.runners.Suite$SuiteClasses(value=[class data.XTest, class data.YTest])";
    String[] parts = input.replaceAll(".*\\[class (.*)\\].*", "$1").split(", class ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

Output:

```
[data.XTest, data.YTest]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use regular expressions.

```
// uses capturing group for characters other than "," "]" and whitespace...
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("class ([^,\\]\\s]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

yields

```
data.XTest
data.YTest
```

for your sample input string. Adapt to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "@org.junit.runners.Suite$SuiteClasses(value=[class data.XTest, class data.YTest])";
String temp = "value=[class ";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf(temp) + temp.length(), s.indexOf("])"));
String[] arr = s.split(", class ");
// sTring[0] = arr[0];
// sTring[1] = arr[1];
System.out.println(arr[0]);
System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
data.XTest
data.YTest
```

Comment: This fails, because it doesn't trim the trailing "])" off of `sTring[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks a lot like the `toString` method of the `Class` class. You might want to use the API that the annotation and the `Class` class make available. I think something like:

```
SuiteClasses a = ...; <- Put the annotation object here instead of calling toString on it
Class[] c = a.value();
sTring[0] = c[0].getName();
sTring[1] = c[1].getName();
```

should to it.

Comment: can't find a value() on Annotation

Comment: You need to declare `a` with the type of your annotation. I have updated my code accordingly.